# Prove that any 3-regular graph with diameter 2 and order 10 is isomorphic to Petersen graph.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

As I was reading this paper **[Classification of Regular Planar Graphs with Diameter Two, DOI: 10.1007/s10114-005-0607-4]**, I noticed a lemma that cites in *Algebraic Graph Theory*.

> Case 3: Let $p=10$.  It is well-known that any $3$-regular graph with diameter $2$ and order $10$ is isomorphic to the Petersen graph [....]

**[2] Biggs, N.: Algebraic Graph Theory, Second Edition, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1993**

But I looked up reference 2, which is the algebraic graph theory book, and unfortunately I didn't find any narrative pointing to this lemma.

I tried to prove it, but it didn't seem easy.

Comment: It seems.to me that this can be disposed of with a case analysis that might be tedious but would be straightforward. It is immediate that the graph has at most 10 vertices, which limits the possibilities.

Comment: @MJD Sorry, I don't quite understand your idea. what is the  case analysis in here.

Comment: @MJD You mean through some computer program to test?

Comment: I was imagining an argument very much like Matthew Daly's below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $G$ be a graph with the stated properties.  Let's label one of the vertices $0$.  It has three neighbors, so let's label them $1$, $2$, and $3$ in some order.  Then we will label the other two neighbors of $1$ with $11$ and $12$ in some order, and so on.  So now as much of the graph as we know about looks like this.

[image]

Since $G$ has ten vertices, we have accounted for all of them.  Note that it was critical that these vertices are all distinct in order to cover ten vertices with 3-regularity and diameter 2, so there can't be any 3-cycles in G.

We are missing two edges on each of the outside vertices, and we need to connect them in such a way that the diameter of the graph is 2.  Without loss of generality, let's attach 11 to 21 and 32.  Now, 11 is within two steps of every vertex except 22 and 31.  If 22 connected to 21, we'd have a 3-cycle, so it must be that 21 connects to 31 and 32 connects to 22.  The only vertices left for 12 to connect to are 22 and 31, and the $G$ now looks like this.

[image]

This is a common diagram of the Petersen graph.  If you need to compare it to the pentagon and pentagram diagram, one 5-cycle is (0, 2, 22, 32, 31) and the other is (1, 11, 21, 31, 12).

Comment: At the point you say "note that it was critical that these vertices are all distinct", why couldn't we have had vertex 21 = vertex 1?

Comment: @MJD Because there are at most three vertices of distance 1 from our "origin" and six vertices of distance 2.  If there were any overlap in those nine vertices, then there would have to be another vertex of distance at least 3 from the origin (since there were ten vertices in all), contrary to our assumption that the diameter was 2.

Comment: Of course, thanks.